# What is actually happening under the hood in Tensorflow's model.fit?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am using Tensorflow's Model subclassing API to use OOP to define a model object that I then train using Tensorflow's `model.fit()` method.

In it, I subclass the training and testing step, as shown in the code below. However, when I train my model using `model.fit()`, for each epoch, it returns one value for the training loss and one value for the validation loss.

I know that a value for the loss is being calculated for each batch because I have a custom loss function that I wrote that calculates loss in a specific way that is necessary for my end goal. However, I don't know what's happening with that loss value *after* it's been calculated. I want to know what's going on under the hood - are the numbers that `model.fit()` displays each epoch the sum of the loss from every batch? Is it the average of the loss from every batch? Sum for training loss and average for validation loss, or vice versa? Something else entirely?

Here is the code for my subclassed model:

```
class Photon_prediction(tf.keras.Model):
    #initialize the model class
    def __init__(self, probability, energy):
        super(Photon_prediction,self).__init__()
        self.probability = probability
        self.energy = energy

    #define the outputs from the model
    def call(self, inputs, training): 
        probability_prediction = self.probability(inputs, training) 
        energy_prediction = self.energy(inputs, training)
        photon_prediction = tf.math.multiply(probability_prediction, energy_prediction)
        return photon_prediction

    #outlines the optimizer(s) to be used (and loss function if I wasn't using a custom loss function)
    def compile(self, optimizer): 
        super(Photon_prediction, self).compile()
        self.optimizer = optimizer

    #custom training routine
    @tf.function
    def train_step(self, Dataset):
        #unbatch the targets and training data to act on them separately in the loss function
        training_data, time, probability_target, energy_target  = Dataset

        #train both the energy and probability predictions together so that both predictions can be used simultaneously
        with tf.GradientTape(persistent = True) as tape:
            #generate energy and probability predictions
            probability_prediction = self.probability(training_data, training = True)
            energy_prediction = self.energy(training_data, training = True)

            #acquire a loss value from the custom loss function
            loss = global_loss(probability_prediction, energy_prediction, time, probability_target, energy_target)

        #apply gradients to the probability sequential model weights
        grads = tape.gradient(loss, self.probability.trainable_weights)
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(
            zip(grads, self.probability.trainable_weights)
        )

        #apply gradients for the energy sequential model weights
        grads = tape.gradient(loss, self.energy.trainable_weights)
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(
            zip(grads, self.probability.trainable_weights)
        )

        return {"I II II L": loss}
    
    #define a validation step
    @tf.function
    def test_step(self, Dataset):
        #unbatch the targets and training data to act on them separately in the loss function
        validation_data, time, probability_target, energy_target = Dataset

        #generate energy and probability predictions
        probability_prediction = self.probability(validation_data, training = False)
        energy_prediction = self.energy(validation_data, training = False)

        #acquire a loss value from the custom loss function
        loss = global_loss(probability_prediction, energy_prediction, time, probability_target, energy_target)

        return {"loss": loss}

def create_model():
    #input shape
    explicit_input_shape = (None, vector_size, num_past_time_steps + 1 + num_future_time_steps)
    implicit_input_shape = (vector_size, num_past_time_steps + 1 + num_future_time_steps)

    #create the probability prediction
    probability = tf.keras.Sequential(
    [
        #Input Layer
        tf.keras.Input(shape = implicit_input_shape),
        
        #Convolutional Layer
        tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters = 64, kernel_size = 5, strides = 1, padding = 'causal',activation = 'gelu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
        
        #Bidirectional LSTM Cell with densely connected neurons
        tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, return_sequences = True)),
        tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, return_sequences = True)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation = 'gelu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
     
        #Second Round of Bidirectional LSTM Cell with densely connected neurons
        tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, return_sequences = True)),
        tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, return_sequences = True)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation = 'gelu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
     
        #Third Round of Bidirectional LSTM Cell with densely connected neurons
        tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, return_sequences = True)),
        tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, return_sequences = True)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation = 'gelu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
        
        #Fourth Round of Bidirectional LSTM Cells with densely connected neurons
        tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, return_sequences = True)),
        tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, return_sequences = True)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(32,activation = 'gelu'),

        #Output Layer (Sigmoid activation forces a value between 0 and 1) + Flattening
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(32,activation = 'gelu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')
    ])

    #create the energy prediction
    energy = tf.keras.Sequential(
    [
        #Input Layer
        tf.keras.Input(shape = implicit_input_shape),
        
        #Convolutional Layer
        tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters = 64, kernel_size = 5, strides = 1, padding = 'causal',activation = 'gelu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
        
        #Bidirectional LSTM Cell with densely connected neurons
        tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, return_sequences = True)),
        tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, return_sequences = True)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation = 'gelu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
        
        #Second Round of Bidirectional LSTM Cell with densely connected neurons
        tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, return_sequences = True)),
        tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, return_sequences = True)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation = 'gelu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
     
        #Third Round of Bidirectional LSTM Cell with densely connected neurons
        tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, return_sequences = True)),
        tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, return_sequences = True)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation = 'gelu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
     
        #Fourth Round of Bidirectional LSTM Cells with densely connected neurons
        tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, return_sequences = True)),
        tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, return_sequences = True)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(32,activation = 'gelu'),

        #Output Layer  + Flattening
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(32,activation = 'gelu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
    ])
    
    #Use the class to instantiate the model
    model = Photon_prediction(probability = probability, energy = energy)
    
    #compile the model with the optimizer
    model.compile(
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
    )

    #building model into a layer DAG so that weights can be loaded
    model.build(explicit_input_shape)

    return model


#model_checkpoint and early stopping callbacks
model_checkpoint = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint("saved_model.h5", save_weights_only = True, save_best_only=True)
lr_schedule = tf.keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler(lambda epoch: 2.5e-6) #figure out optimal learning rate commented --> epoch: 1e-6* 10**(epoch / 20)
early_stopping = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor = 'val_loss', patience= 5, restore_best_weights=True)

#build model 
epochs = 300
model = create_model()
model.summary()

#fit model
history = model.fit(dataset_train, epochs=epochs,validation_data=dataset_val, callbacks=[model_checkpoint, lr_schedule, early_stopping])
```

**TL; DR**: I want to know how `model.fit()` is generating the number returned by the `val_loss` metric and `I II II L` metric. Specifically, I am curious if it is an average over the loss from each batch, the sum of the loss from each batch, or if it is calculated in some other way?

```
Epoch 1/300
2999/2999 [==============================] - 446s 107ms/step - I II II L: 3605715.6514 - val_loss: 58142.5117 - lr: 2.5000e-06
Epoch 2/300
 475/2999 [===>..........................] - ETA: 3:36 - I II II L: 234723.3328
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyboardInterrupt                         Traceback (most recent call last)
```

**EDIT**:
I have been asked to provide my custom loss function. It isn't needed to be able to answer my question, which is why I didn't include it initially. Regardless, if it helps with understanding the architecture of my model, here it is:

```
def global_loss(predicted_probability, predicted_energy, time, true_probability, true_energy):
    #from the input data, get everything to have a shape of [None, span] None is a placeholder in graph execution for batch_size
    predicted_probability = tf.cast(tf.squeeze(predicted_probability, axis = -1), tf.float32)
    predicted_energy = tf.cast(tf.squeeze(predicted_energy, axis = -1), tf.float32)
    t = tf.cast(time, tf.float32)
    true_energy = tf.cast(true_energy, tf.float32)
    true_probability = tf.cast(true_probability, tf.float32)

    #predicted photon count loss
    predicted_photon_count = tf.math.reduce_sum(predicted_probability)
    true_photon_count = tf.math.reduce_sum(true_probability)
    predicted_photon_count_loss = tf.math.square(predicted_photon_count - true_photon_count)

    #predicted photon energy loss
    predicted_photon_energy = tf.math.reduce_sum(tf.math.multiply(predicted_probability, predicted_energy))
    true_photon_energy = tf.math.reduce_sum(true_energy)
    predicted_photon_energy_loss = tf.math.square(predicted_photon_energy - true_photon_energy)

    #predicted energy variance loss
    predicted_energy_variance = tf.math.reduce_sum(tf.math.multiply(tf.math.square(tf.math.subtract(predicted_energy, predicted_photon_energy)), predicted_probability))
    true_energy_variance = tf.math.reduce_sum(tf.math.square(tf.math.subtract(true_energy, true_photon_energy)))
    predicted_energy_variance_loss = tf.square(predicted_energy_variance - true_energy_variance)

    #predicted photon incidence loss
    predicted_photon_incidence = tf.math.reduce_sum(tf.math.multiply(t, predicted_probability))
    true_photon_incidence = tf.math.reduce_sum(tf.math.multiply(t,true_probability))
    predicted_photon_incidence_loss = tf.math.square(predicted_photon_incidence - true_photon_incidence)

    #predicted time variance loss
    predicted_time_variance = tf.math.reduce_sum(tf.math.multiply(tf.math.square(tf.math.subtract(t, predicted_photon_incidence)), predicted_probability))
    true_time_variance = tf.math.reduce_sum(tf.math.multiply(tf.math.square(tf.math.subtract(t, true_photon_incidence)), true_probability))
    predicted_time_variance_loss = tf.math.square(predicted_time_variance - true_time_variance)

    #weighting
    photon_count_weight = tf.constant(1e2, dtype=tf.float32) * predicted_photon_count_loss
    photon_energy_weight = tf.constant(5e1, dtype=tf.float32) * predicted_photon_energy_loss
    energy_variance_weight = tf.constant(1, dtype=tf.float32) * predicted_energy_variance_loss
    photon_incidence_weight = tf.constant(1, dtype=tf.float32) * predicted_photon_incidence_loss
    time_variance_weight = tf.constant(1e2, dtype=tf.float32) * predicted_time_variance_loss

    
    #returning loss differently based on whether a photon is in the batch 
    global_loss = tf.cond(
            pred = tf.math.equal(true_photon_count, tf.constant(0., dtype = tf.float32)),
            true_fn = lambda: photon_count_weight,
            false_fn = lambda: photon_count_weight + photon_energy_weight + energy_variance_weight + photon_incidence_weight + time_variance_weight
        )

    return global_loss
```

Comment: where is your loss function defined? :'D

Comment: My loss function is somewhat complex and it isn't really important for the scope of my question, which is why I didn't include it. All you need to know is that my loss function returns a single value to characterize the loss of a single batch. I want to know what `model.fit()` is doing with that value when it tracks the training and validation loss metrics across an epoch

Comment: I edited my question to add the loss function, even though it isn't necessary for the scope of my question.

Comment: Just check the source code https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.10.0/keras/engine/training.py#L1214-L1638

Comment: It is always an average, this has been asked at least two more times here, always try to find the duplicate question to yours.

Comment: I did try to find a duplicate question to mine (it's much easier to read someone else's question than to write my own), and was unable to locate one. Can you link to such a duplicate?